# Kendo UI Fails to Bind ViewModel

Tags: kendo-ui

I’m not sure just how much detail I can provide or how much is necessary here, but-

I’m trying to upgrade an application from Kendo UI v2015.1.429 to v2019.1.220. However, it is failing when I try to bind a particular viewmodel to an element, throwing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

I’ve managed to track what I believe is the cause of this bug to the inferSelect function, in the code below. However, as far as I can tell, everything involved is or should be defined and this error should not be happening. It's working perfectly fine for a viewmodel on another page, and it works if I remove one specific element that I'm trying to bind the viewmodel to, but I can't find any reason for that element to fail.

What further information should I provide/investigate to fix this?

```js
function inferSelect(select, fields) {
            select = $(select)[0];
            var options = select.options;
            var firstField = fields[0];
            var secondField = fields[1];
            var data = [];
            var idx, length;
            var optgroup;
            var option;
            var record;
            var value;
            for (idx = 0, length = options.length; idx < length; idx++) {
-->             record = {}; //The error is thrown on this line  
                ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED. I was trying to bind a [multiselect](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect) widget to an `<input>` rather than to an actual `<select>`. Thanks Kendo for giving such an informative error message.